# MySQL full text search with delimiters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, full-text-search

I have a MySQL table with a 'tags' field, which is using a FULLTEXT index. This field contains a list of comma separated values i.e 'books, toys, chocolate coloured sofa'.

```
SELECT * FROM Store WHERE MATCH(Store.tags) AGAINST ('"chocolate"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

The (above) example query is matching records containing 'chocolate coloured sofa'.  I would only like to retrieve records which contain 'chocolate' within the delimiters (in this case commas).  In other words I would expect that the example record would fail the match.

I have looked at the MySQL manual including  MySQL [Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) but I cannot see any way this could be achieved.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last tag has comma, you can search adding the comma:

```
SELECT * FROM Store WHERE MATCH(Store.tags) AGAINST ('"chocolate,"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But be careful with tags less than 4 characters, its aren't matched... well, you can configure it in my.ini

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest solution to implement. I will ensure that each tag is stripped of leading and tailing white space and is enclosed in commas. I can then match against '",chocolate,"'. For example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize your table, so each tag will be saved in its own row.

Else you'll have to patch and rebuild MySQL to add the space character to the set of word characters. That link you provided has all instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. Unfortunately normalisation is not an option due to the performance overhead on performing the large amount of joins that would be required.  If I attempted your second recommendation would it still be possible to perform matches on phrases that contain spaces, i.e 'leather sofa'?